# Browser mode and document mode in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, browser

I use the Developer Tools in IE9 to switch between IE7, 8 & 9 Browser Modes for testing markup & CSS. I use following combinations.

IE7 Browser Mode + Document mode IE7 Standards

IE8 Browser Mode + Document mode IE8 Standards

IE9 Browser Mode + Document mode IE9 Standards

But, if i use following combination, few design's position issues are occured.

IE9 Browser Mode + IE7 Standards

Is the above combination valid? or Does i need to change Document mode forcefully?

Answer (score 3):

The one thing to bear in mind when testing using IE's various compatibility modes is that they are not exact duplicates of a real copy of IE8 or IE7. There are known bugs and quirks in the various different modes that do not occur in a real copy of IE7 or IE8.

Your question is asking which of the modes is sufficient for testing. My answer would be that none of them are. If you really want to know whether the site works in IE7 and IE8, you need to test it in IE7 and IE8.

Yes, testing in IE9 with a fallback mode will give you a close approximation of the old browser versions, but you'll never be totally certain it's correct. And at the end of the day, the point of testing is to get that certainty.