# Using Browser and Document mode settings correctly

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-9, document, mode

I have a wordpress site with  ie html5.

Its fine in IE9,7 FF, Ch, Op and Saf. However, IE8 might be giving problems on one page http://www.haywardsdrycleaners.com/services/

I say might because I am confused about how to test it with IE 9. If I set the "Browser mode" to IE8 then as the page refreshes the document mode stays on "IE 9 standards (page default)". Like this everything displays perfectly. However, if I leave Browser Mode on IE8 and click Document mode to IE8 the layout goes wrong.

My question is if I had the "Real" IE8 installed then would the page be ok or not! I do realise that this mode is only an approx as per [Browser mode and document mode in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116056/browser-mode-and-document-mode-in-ie9)

Thanks

E

Comment: acutally I have just retested after closing and opening IE9. I now find that when I set BM to IE8 the doc mode changes to IE8 standards and this call apart. What should I do???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just went to that page in the real Internet Explorer 8 on Windows 7 and the layout is, indeed, messed up. You can test it yourself for free using an official virtual machine:

[Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Image](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575)

The virtual machine even works in VirtualBox.

Comment: Thanks for looking - and for the bad news!

Comment: You're welcome. Do you feel like I accurately answered your question? Your question was: if I had the "Real" IE8 installed then would the page be ok or not